# iptables nat just port 25?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

im trying to configure a firewall.
It has to network interfaces, eth0 (lan) and eth1 (wan).

```
allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
gateway 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.16.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.16.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Behind eth1 is a router that gives me an dynamic ip.

I the same machine, there is a web-proxy. Actually, the computer on the lan can access the web only using the proxy. Now, i need machines in the lan to access SMTP and POP3 servers over the internet. So i need NAT, but just for port 25 and 110. I dont want to nat other ports.

Can you help me to configure iptables step by step (im really noob at iptables)?

Regards

Comment: Hi there!

Did you solve this problem? I'm stuck here too :(

Comment: I've read your comments to the answers below, and I have to first ask a question: What's the Default Gateway of the clients? Where do the clients get their IP addresses?

Comment: Please post your current iptables rules so that we know which part contains the blocking. Only then it's possible to give the command needed to bypass that block in your exact environment. I'd suggest that you first got your NAT fully functional and only then locked it down to only allow specific destination ports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below will do the job. Iptables is easy enough to work with - you just have to be explicit about telling it what to do with traffic that comes from or goes to specific locations on specific ports. Although you only requested ports 25 and 110, I included options for secure SMTP and secure POP3 as well.

What I recommend below takes into account whatever firewall rules you have in place and puts the rules you've requested higher in the processing order than anything else. Iptables processes rules in the order that it matches them, so just in case you have other rules already in the firewall that might block SMTP or POP3, I used the insert command and specified the rules should be placed at the top of the list. If you don't have any other firewall rules, then you could substitute the "-I" with "-A" and drop the line numbers after the "FORWARD" and "POSTROUTING" tables.

I recommend implementing connection tracking whenever you can and the first iptables rule below turns that on. If you're running on a really old kernel then you might have issues with these commands, but if they work for you, then great. If they don't, then drop that first line, and drop the "-m tcp" portion of all the other lines.

```
#Enable IP Forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#Turn on connection tracking
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow SMTP traffic out to the internet. This includes regular and authenticated SMTP
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 3 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

#Allow POP3 traffic out to the internet. This includes regular and SSL secured POP3
iptables -I FORWARD 4 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 5 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

#NAT the traffic leaving your router for the allowed forwarded ports above
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 465 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 3 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 587 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 4 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 110 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 5 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 995 -j MASQUERADE

#Optionally, block any other forwarded traffic
iptables -I FORWARD 6 -i eth1 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Hey, i did all the steps, but i get this (from the lan).
could not resolve mailserver.com/25: Name or service not known :( any idea?

Comment: Maybe because the firewall is not the defalt gateway? :(

Comment: exactly ... look at the comment on my answer.

Comment: Another thing ... if you dont have an internal DNS, you should consider `iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I've tried this solution but it won't work in my network...
Outlook keeps on givine me errors :(

Comment: Why the roundabout way of `-I POSTROUTING <n>`? Just use `-A POSTROUTING` (`-A` == Append to chain, as opposed to `-I` == insert into chain)

Comment: I suggested using the -I flag because I don't know what his current iptables rules list looks like. This ensures that the rules actually take affect regardless of whatever else he has below.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 110 -j MASQUERADE

:)

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.16.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.16.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Is wrong (or a typo ;)). `broadcast` should be `192.168.16.255`.

Asuming that every computer has as its default gateway this linux box (`192.168.16.6`) it is just a matter of configuring ip forwarding:

```
 # Enable ip forward:
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
 # The same cam be achieved by:
 #  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

 # Forwarding traffic between interfaces:
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 --src 192.168.16.0/24 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 --src 192.168.16.0/24 -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
 # This rule prevents other traffic to be dropped
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 --src 192.168.16.0/24 -j DROP

 # Masquerade traffic to the outside world:
 # If the public ip is a dynamic one use MASQUERADE
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 --src 192.168.16.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

 # If the public ip is a static one, use SNAT
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 --src 192.168.16.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source <pub_ip>
```

When the public connection comes up, if it creates a ppp link,then you'll have to replace `eth1` with, let's say, `ppp0`.

**BEAWARE**: this is by no means a strong firewall, it is just a minimal set of rules to do what you want.

Comment: Nope, the default gateway is not that machine, is the router. This is only the firewall :(

Comment: If this is not the default gateway, then the router should send everything through this host ... In general, if the firewall is not the default gateway, it is the nexthop after the router (or a stealth one between the router and the rest of the net).

Comment: yes, the firewall is between the router and the wan. Should i configure the router?